# A very unique Web Question

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

I got this link from a friend of mine, it's supposed to be really hard to understand.

Could you help me get the hidden text?

[image]

[Source](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/csh-static/all_your_base/04d6afa880b76ca48e21ec43094a7ddb31e552fcb0ca7b931e2837f66b249629.html)

Answer (score 5):

The linked page contains a segment of javascript code. With some line spacing to make it somewhat more readable, it looks like this:

> `function r(){for(var r=0,e=0,a="",l=0;l<n.length;l++)if(n[l].toLowerCase()!=n[l]&&(r+=1),8==++e){if(!t)return;a+=String.fromCharCode(r),r=0,e=0}else r<<=1;return a}`
>  `var e=!1,t=!1,`
>  `a=setInterval(function(){e&&(t=!0,alert("Your flag is: "+r()),clearInterval(a));t=!1},1e3),`
>  `n="hHBudYDbtLYvFIkftFJmpkrXtKImhMNCiULIJqZOnEbhifbSiEusXMetaRGsTJrlrAaTQWZRnNLZQjmKmcSPlnywnJHVuLsSyIqInmCetDyRYXPSpiXHxUXwzVTpqhqZazKsnYiygXyioSfXjIzAUTYZpSyllknszSQMlzQnrgVIycFObAjKSZZFgDNyecIliWNqcDzAbFujFZrmdFMoTGKHsMNfAQSoqOBocHCCtEcRHZHOtOAPgJqiwbSIlfyivGaWSZBIbLaMlKdIoYgJhgTYyXVNEQfB";`

This code does not do anything in this form, so it needed some tweaking:

> In the function inside the `setInterval(...)`, the popup message won't appear because the variables `e` and `t` are false. You can change this by editing the line 
>  `var e=!1,t=!1,`
>  into
>  `var e=1,t=1,`

The resulting popup message appears with this text:

> `Your flag is: flag{ALl_y0uR_6a$E_@r3_beLong_t0_US}`

Comment: @shays Was this popup message the expect result, or is there more to the puzzle?

Answer (score 2):

> When you inspect the source page, there is a little script:
>  `function r(){for(var r=0,e=0,a="",l=0;l<n.length;>l++)if(n[l].toLowerCase()!=n[l]&&(r+=1),8==++e){if(!t)return;a+=String.fromCharCode(r),r=0,e=0}else r<<=1;return a}var e=!1,t=!1,a=setInterval(function(){e&&(t=!0,alert("Your flag is: "+r()),clearInterval(a));t=!1},1e3),n="hHBudYDbtLYvFIkftFJmpkrXtKImhMNCiULIJqZOnEbhifbSiEusXMetaRGsTJrlrAaTQWZRnNLZQjmKmcSPlnywnJHVuLsSyIqInmCetDyRYXPSpiXHxUXwzVTpqhqZazKsnYiygXyioSfXjIzAUTYZpSyllknszSQMlzQnrgVIycFObAjKSZZFgDNyecIliWNqcDzAbFujFZrmdFMoTGKHsMNfAQSoqOBocHCCtEcRHZHOtOAPgJqiwbSIlfyivGaWSZBIbLaMlKdIoYgJhgTYyXVNEQfB";`
>  It seems to be like a simple Javascript CTF game.